# Racket - A function that takes a set as input, and outputs its power set

Tags: set, scheme, racket, powerset

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a set as an argument and returns its power set, also as a set of sets.

Example use:

```
(power-set (set 1 2)) 
; is supposed to output
=> (set (set) (set 1) (set 2) (set 1 2))
```

What I have so far is this:

```
(define (power-set st)
  (if (set-empty? st) (set (set))
    (let ((ps (power-set (set-rest st))))
      (set-union ps 
                 (set-map (lambda (subset) 
                              (set-add (set-first st) subset)) 
                          ps)))))
```

But instead, DrRacket is throwing an error on the line containing `set-map`:

[image: Thrown Error Message]

Is there anything I can do to my function to make it execute correctly? It seems like there's something wrong with "`set-map`" or "`lambda`" perhaps?

Comment: `set-add` takes a set as its _first_ argument; likewise with `set-map`. And `set-map` returns a list, not a set; you can use `list->set` to construct a set from the list returned by `set-map`.

Comment: @exnihilo okay, thank you. But how would I go about implementing list->set? I tried putting list->set in front of and right after the set-map call, and that ceases to work as well.

Comment: @exnihilo also, sorry about these questions that may be considered basic-level, I'm a complete newbie to racket.

Comment: I'll write up a quick answer....

Comment: @exnihilo alright, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things causing you grief in the posted code: the order of arguments in a couple of procedure calls, and the return type of one procedure call.

The `set-add` procedure takes a `set` as its first argument, so the arguments here need to be interchanged:

```
(set-add subset (set-first st))
```

Similarly, `set-map` takes a `set` as its first argument, and a procedure as its second:

```
(set-map ps
         (lambda (subset) (set-add subset (set-first st))))
```

Now, somewhat counter-intuitively, `set-map` returns a `list`, not a `set`; But, `set-union` is looking for a `set`. To give `set-union` what it wants, you can use `list->set` to construct a `set` from the `list`:

```
(list->set (set-map ps
                    (lambda (subset) (set-add subset (set-first st)))))
```

Taken together:

```
(define (power-set st)
  (if (set-empty? st) (set (set))
      (let ((ps (power-set (set-rest st))))
        (set-union ps
                   (list->set
                    (set-map
                     ps
                     (lambda (subset) (set-add subset (set-first st)))))))))
```

A couple of sample runs:

```
scratch.rkt> (power-set (set 1 2))
(set (set 1) (set) (set 1 2) (set 2))
scratch.rkt> (power-set (set 1 2 3))
(set (set 1) (set 1 3) (set 1 3 2) (set 3 2) (set) (set 1 2) (set 2) (set 3))
```